# RUN Task Scheduler in different times

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to create TS (Windows Server 2012 R2) for below timings in everyday?

9:00, 15:00, 19:00 and 3:00

I have idea to create TS for every 6 hours in a day, but i have a 4 hours gap between 15:00 and 19:00.

any idea?

~~Ramesh

Comment: Is this using crontab?

Comment: Sorry, this is for Windows Server 2012 R2.